# modular arithmetic proof involving multiplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Suppose $u,v,x,y,z$ are integers such that $u \equiv v (modx)$ and $y \equiv z (modx)$.

Prove that $uz \equiv vy (modx)$

I know that by modular multiplication the equation can be written as:

$uy \equiv vz (modx)$. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: If $y\equiv z(mod\; x)$ then $z\equiv y(mod\;x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always go back to first principles.

$$u \equiv v \pmod x \implies u = kx + v, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$y \equiv z \pmod x \implies y = mx + z \implies z = y - mx, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Hence,

$$uz = (kx + v)(y-mx) = kxy + vy - kmx^2 - vmx\\ = vy + (ky - kmx - vm)x \equiv vy \pmod x$$

It's not the quickest proof, but it's easy to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

$\left\{\begin{matrix} u\equiv v \pmod{x}\Rightarrow uz\equiv vz \pmod{x}\\z\equiv y \pmod{x}\Rightarrow vz\equiv vy \pmod{x}\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow uz\equiv vz \equiv vy \pmod{x}$

PS. Sorry, I'm still not comfortable here and have no rights to write comments.